# Excel 2013 crashes intermittently at least once a day

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

i have a user running Windows7 Ent x64 8gigs ram in a domain environment. Excel 2013(32bit) keeps crashing intermittently at least once a day. Thus far i have:

- tried Excel safe mode
- checked graphics hardware acceleration in advanced Excel options
- disabled add-ins ( user only has one add-in though, ie ASAP Utilities)
- checked default printer
- cleared %temp%
- repaired Excel 2013

The user claims to be working on the file then it just crashes. Yesterday she was selecting cells(Ctrl D, or something) then it crashed. today she mailed me again that it crashed. The files are located on a share drive and accessed her colleagues don't have any issues working with the files. Please see event log below? Anyone help?

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4569.1504, time stamp: 0x52c5e9e1
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4569.1504, time stamp: 0x52c5e9e1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000747a3
Faulting process id: 0xd18
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0fa8452c15864
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: 5ad80fe9-6684-11e5-84c3-1803731facd1
```

Answer (score 0):

Common causes of excel crash are formatting and calculation. Maybe you should take a look of that in your excel. Excessive formatting or calculation may crash your excel.